# Seleção com LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Estou estudando sql e eu não sei se isso é possível. Mas tenho a seguintes tabelas:

Tabela **`contatos`**

```
______________________

id | nome | sobrenome |
______________________
```

Que contém apenas um contato:

```
1 | andrei | coelho |
```

E tenho uma outra tabela:

Tabela **`contatos_telefone`**

```
____________________________

id | id_contato | telefone |
___________________________
```

Nesta tabela eu tenho 2 registros:

```
1 | 1 | 9999999 |
2 | 1 | 8888888 |
```

Eu usei o `LEFT JOIN` da seguinte forma:

```
    SELECT contatos.id as id_contato, contatos.nome as nome, 
    contatos.sobrenome as sobrenome, contatos_telefone.telefone 
    FROM contatos LEFT JOIN contatos_telefone 
    ON contatos.id = contatos_telefone.id_contato
    ORDER BY contatos.nome
```

Ele me retorna isso:

```
 [id_contato] => 1 [nome] => Andrei [sobrenome] => Coelho [telefone] => 9999999
 [id_contato] => 1 [nome] => Andrei [sobrenome] => Coelho [telefone] => 8888888
```

Eu queria saber se é possível fazer algo assim com o `sql`:

```
 [id_contato] => 1 [nome] => Andrei [sobrenome] => Coelho array(telefones 
 [0] => 8888888 [1] => 9999999)
```

Pois gostaria que ele agrupasse pelo nome. Eu tentei usar o `GROUP BY`, mas não consegui. Ele me trouxe apenas um registro de telefone.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
    contatos.id as id_contato, 
    contatos.nome as nome, 
    contatos.sobrenome as sobrenome, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(contatos_telefone.telefone SEPARATOR ',') AS telefones
FROM contatos 
LEFT JOIN contatos_telefone ON contatos.id = contatos_telefone.id_contato
GROUP BY contatos.id, contatos.nome, contatos.sobrenome
ORDER BY contatos.nome
```

E retornar todos os telefones em uma só coluna.

Salvo engano, se não informar o `SEPARATOR`, ele retorna o array:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(contatos_telefone.telefone)
```

Comment: Vc me ajudando denovo? rsrs Obrigado!

Comment: precisar... estamos aí =]